# Swift - Alert says website is blocked when trying to access a page that should be allowed

Tags: ios, swift, uikit, webkit, uialertcontroller

I have this code, which is supposed to block the user from visiting websites that are not safe by checking their host:

```
    func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, decidePolicyFor navigationAction: WKNavigationAction, decisionHandler: @escaping (WKNavigationActionPolicy) -> Void) {
        let url = navigationAction.request.url
        
        if let host = url?.host {
            for website in websites {
                if host.contains(website) {
                    decisionHandler(.allow)
                    return
                }
            }
        }
        
        decisionHandler(.cancel)
        
        let ac = UIAlertController(title: "The website you are trying to visiting is not allowed", message: nil, preferredStyle: .alert)
        ac.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel))
        present(ac, animated: true)
    }
```

However, whenever I open any website on my list, the alert pops over, as if the website is not safe.

Here is my websites string:

```
var websites = ["smithsonianmag.com", "bigthink.com", "theonion.com", "oddee.com", "apartmenttherapy.com", "coolthings.com"]
```

I tried the following on Playgrounds to try and understand if there was a problem with the websites I have

```
import UIKit
import WebKit

var websites = ["smithsonianmag.com", "bigthink.com", "theonion.com", "oddee.com", "apartmenttherapy.com", "coolthings.com"]

for website in websites {
    let url = URL(string: "https://" + website)
    let host = url?.host
    print("host:" + host!)
}
```

but it seemed fine, as the outputs were the following:

```
host:smithsonianmag.com
host:bigthink.com
host:theonion.com
host:oddee.com
host:apartmenttherapy.com
host:coolthings.com
```

What am I doing wrong with my code or even with the Playgrounds check?

Comment: Add print in your code: Before `if host.contains(website)` add: `print("\(host) contains \(website): \(host.contains(website))")` and see the result?

Comment: Oh, God. I see it now. It keeps on loading external links on each url - such as adds - and while the page loads, it checks my website against the host of the website from the add loaded on the page.

Answer (score 0):

After Larme's suggestion, I added the print line in my code. Then I could see that, while the website loaded, the print function had lots of different and unexpected outputs.

The website would load when it reached something like this:

```
coolthings.com contains smithsonianmag.com: false
coolthings.com contains bigthink.com: false
coolthings.com contains theonion.com: false
coolthings.com contains oddee.com: false
coolthings.com contains apartmenttherapy.com: false
coolthings.com contains coolthings.com: true
```

However, it kept going and when adds were loaded on the page, I would get the alert saying that the website was not allowed, and the following outputs of the print function:

```
googleads.g.doubleclick.net contains smithsonianmag.com: false
googleads.g.doubleclick.net contains bigthink.com: false
googleads.g.doubleclick.net contains theonion.com: false
googleads.g.doubleclick.net contains oddee.com: false
googleads.g.doubleclick.net contains apartmenttherapy.com: false
googleads.g.doubleclick.net contains coolthings.com: false
```

So I guess the code above is not the best solution to use when checking if a website is part of my list of allowed websites.

For now, simply removing "not allowed" alert lets the page load and the user can't follow a link and be redirected to a website that is not on the safe list, which was the desired effect.

I will work on a better solution for this and post it here later. It will hopefully help someone with the same issue.

Comment: Maybe print `navigation.type`, `navigation.sourceFrame` or `navigation.targetFrame` could be there a common value that might help you filter